# How to change the input value when entering the new value

Tags: javascript

I have an input with placeholder="YYYY/MM", when the user click the input to enter the data, I want the year and month to dissappear, so only "/" stays.

I already try with my code, however it doesn't work, please help/

```js
var birthdayId = "document.querySelector("#BIRTHDAY")";
if(birthdayId.maxlength < 4){
birthdayId.value = "/";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="BIRTHDAY" name="BIRTHDAY" placeholder="YYYY/MM" maxlength="7" value="YYYY/MM">
```

Comment: You will want to do your logic in a `focus` event listener

Comment: This is called an input mask. There are plugins that will do it.

Comment: @Taplar How to do that with focus event listener?

Comment: @Barmar I can't use plugin since the platform is limited

Comment: @Udzzzz Have a look https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/jOqmPxW

Comment: @PGSystemTester It's almost correct, however, when I try to enter the value, the "/" dissapear, is there a way we can do this without "/" to dissapear?

Comment: Why do you have `"document.querySelector("#BIRTHDAY")"` in quotes? That makes it a string literal, it doesn't call the function.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky Thank you, that's the answer I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your code in a `focus` event listener.

You should be checking the length of the value, not the `maxlength` property, which never changes.

You shouldn't put the call to `document.querySelector` in quotes.

Don't set the default value of the input to `YYYY/MM`, since that will prevent the length test from working. The placeholder is used to display the desired format, you don't need to do it with value as well.

```js
var birthdayId = document.querySelector("#BIRTHDAY");
birthdayId.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  if (birthdayId.value.length < 4) {
    birthdayId.value = "/";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="BIRTHDAY" name="BIRTHDAY" placeholder="YYYY/MM" maxlength="7" value="">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for some reason, when I test your code, run code snippet, the value is disable or I can't enter any value

Comment: Since I fill the value with 7 characters, it's at the maximum length. You have to delete characters so you can replace them.

Comment: I changed it to just initialize the input with `/` as in your code. But now you can't see how many digits have to be on either side of the `/`.

Comment: Doing a real mask will require much more complex code, and I wouldn't do it without a plugin. Since you said you can't use a plugin, you don't get it here.